# show single page by using id

Tags: php, laravel

I want to go to specific page after click show button but after click show will get this error Undefined offset: 1

web.php

```
Route::get('/product/{id}', 'ProductController@show')->name('product.show');
```

ProductController.php

```
public function show($id)
{  
    $product = Product::find($id);
    return view('product.show')->with(compact('product'));
}
```

home.blade.php

```
<div class="row">

  @foreach($products as $product)

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">
          <a href="">{{ $product->name }}</a>
        </h4>
        
        <h5>{{ $product->price }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{ $product->description }}</p>
        <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('product.show', $product->id ) }}">Show</a></td>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  @endforeach

</div>
```

Comment: which version laravel you are using, php artisan -V

Comment: I use laravel 7

Comment: do you have product on database.

Comment: yes I have the product

Answer (score 0):

Your are doing wrong in blade file. Note here php array start from 0. So array is [0,1,2,3] and database id is start from 1.

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct link

```
 {{ route('product.show', ['Product' => $product->id]) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like below code

```
{{ route('product.show', ['id' => $product->id]) }}

return view('product.show', compact('product'));
```

And in your `show.blade.php` you have to use like below

```
{{$product->id}} or {{$product->name}} //etc //But not use foorloop
```

Comment: same error Undefined offset: 1
http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/1

Comment: @MohamadAmirul I update my answer. Please check again

Answer (score 0):

The `find` method will return only one item. You can't use the loop on it.

Try the following code.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/product/{product}', 'ProductController@show')->name('product.show');
```

**ProductController.php**

```
public function show(Product $product)
{  
    return view('product.show')->with(compact('product'));
}
```

**home.blade.php**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">
          <a href="">{{ $product->name }}</a>
        </h4>
        
        <h5>{{ $product->price }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{ $product->description }}</p>
        <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('product.show', $product->id ) }}">Show</a></td>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**you are in wrong blade**

you are returning product.show blade in your controller:

```
  return view('product.show')->with(compact('product'));
```

but you put home.blade code!!!

put the right blade code

Answer (score -1):

show.php: Why not try it $_ Get["id"]

Comment: Because you should not use `$_GET` in Laravel directly